# Trying to find a textbox control in InsertItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm currently trying to find a textbox control in InsertItemTemplate to test against values already in one of my database tables but I can't seem to get the FindControl to work. Below is the code I'm currently looking at:

```
    protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    TextBox linkinsTextBox = Page.FindControl("linkinsTextBox") as TextBox;
    String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UniString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    myConnection.Open();

    bool exists = false;

    //The number of entries in links is counted
    String linkCountQuery = " SELECT COUNT(link) from[links] where link = " + linkinsTextBox.Text + "";

    SqlCommand linkCountQueryCommand = new SqlCommand(linkCountQuery, myConnection);
    Int32 linkCountQueryCommandValue = (Int32)linkCountQueryCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    myConnection.Close();

    if (linkCountQueryCommandValue >= 1)
    {
        exists = true;
        URLexists.Text = "URL already exists. Please enter a different URL.";
    }

}
```

Comment: FindControl is not a recursive method.  It won't drill down into controls in the hope of finding what you're looking for.  You need to give it a specific parent to look in.

Comment: @HugoYates is there any way to specify the InsertItemTemplate?

Comment: you should just target the listview where your template is so for example `MyListView.FindControl("LinkinsTextBox")`. Also you want to be very careful, your input is going straight into your SQL Query making you an easy target for an SQL Injection attack.